# After Lan to Wan Setup how to connect 1st router computers communicate to 2nd router computers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

I have some issue i hope someone help me for this issues I have with my Office network. I have a TPLink ER6120 VPN Router and currently I added a Cisco Linksys EA 6900 dual band router. i have configure 2 routers with LAN to WAN Setup

**1st TPLink ER6120 Router**

IP: 192.168.1.1
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DCHP: ON
Connected to the ISP

**2nd Cisco Linksys EA6900 Router**
IP: 192.168.2.1
Gateway: 192.168.2.1
DCHP: ON
Connect this router Wan to 1st Tplink Router Lan

after configure Lan to Wan setup internet is now working in 2nd router connected computers but issue is my 1st router can't ping and communicate with 2nd router gateway 192.168.2.1 and can't ping any computer of connect 2nd router. how to communicate this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your Cisco router into a bridge mode, so both your routers are in the same subnet 192.168.1/24

or

You have to add a route from your TPLink router to your Cisco router, i.e.:

```
192.168.2/24 -> your Cisco router IP in 192.168.1/24 subnet
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "Static router" on your computer in the first network (to tell him where to deliver the packets to the other network). Make sure that you have a static address on the WAN port of the second router. You can google "Static Router" for more information.